# Selecting highest three values from a Python Dictionary

Tags: python

I am supposed to select the highest three values from a dictionary without sorting it or importing additional packages. So far I was only able to select the highest value.

```
print("enter a string s")
s = input()
frequency = {}

for i in s:
    if i in frequency:
        frequency[i] = frequency[i]+1
    elif i == ' ':
        pass
    else:
            frequency[i] = 1
a = max(frequency, key=frequency.get)
```

How could I select the other values ??

Comment: Could you give an example input/output you're looking for?

Comment: Why can't you sort it?

Comment: He's doing an exercice for school or so.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The constraints of your problem seem strange.

This is not the best way to solve this problem.

Nonetheless, remove the most frequent value from the dictionary and then repeat the procedure.

```py
print("enter a string s")
s = input()
frequency = {}

for i in s:
    if i in frequency:
        frequency[i] = frequency[i]+1
    elif i == ' ':
        pass
    else:
        frequency[i] = 1
a = max(frequency, key=frequency.get)
del frequency[a]
b = max(frequency, key=frequency.get)
del frequency[b]
c = max(frequency, key=frequency.get)
del frequency[c]
```

Comment: Hey, thank you very much. Yeah it is strange but that was the task :)))

Answer (score 0):

You can find the highest value, remove it from the dictionary and then run your algorithm again on the dictionary.

Answer (score -1):

I would like to note that your for loop can be written a bit simpler, like the following:

```py
for i in s:
    if i in frequency:
        frequency[i] +=1
    elif i != ' ':
        frequency[i] = 1
```

You should *never* use if statements with pass in order for the else clause not  to become executed, as you can always simplify them.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question.

Comment: Oh thats a nice hint though. Thank you